# Filtering data from one menu to another menu

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have a checkbox in Manufacturing module-> Products form (Named "Raw Materials")

If I select the checkbox and save the data it should not get saved in the products form but else it should be saved in a separate menu called Raw materials which I created manually in Manufacturing module.

How to achieve this in Odoo v10?

This is my xml file......

```
<record id="raw_materials" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">raw.form.inherit.button</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml" >
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="after">
                     <div name="options" groups="base.group_user">
                            <div>
                                <field name="raw"/>
                                <label for="raw"/>
                            </div>
                      </div>    

             </xpath>
             </field>
</record>



<record id="product_template_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.search</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Product">
                <separator/>
                <filter string="Raw Materials" name="filter_to_raw" domain="[('raw','=',True)]"/>
                <separator/>
            </search>
        </field>
</record>

<record id="product_raw_materials" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Raw Materials</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">product.template</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="context">{"search_default_filter_to_raw":1}</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="product.product_template_kanban_view"/>
            <field name="search_view_id" ref="product.product_template_search_view"/>
            <field name="help" type="html">
              <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                Click to define a new product.
              </p><p>
                You must define a product for everything you sell, whether it's
                a physical product, a consumable or a service you offer to
                customers.
              </p><p>
                The product form contains information to simplify the Raw Materials: price, notes in the quotation, accounting data,
                procurement methods, etc.
              </p>
            </field>
        </record>



       <menuitem id="menu_mrp_product_form" name="Raw Materials" action="mrp.product_template_action"
                 parent="mrp.menu_mrp_bom" sequence="8"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You have to inherit the save button first @Aravind Mano

Comment: But in that Products form already there are two check boxes in which one  is used to save the data in Sales module-> Products and other one is used to save the data in Purchase module-> Products. I want the same action to be performed when i click on Raw materials check box

Answer (score 0):

1. Override the Create function
2. check whether the boolen(True/False)
3. IF true create a dictionary pass the form values

Ex:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals.get('boolean_field') == True:
        product_data= {
                    'name':vals.get('partner_name'),
                    'size':vals.get('size'),
                    'price':vals.get('price'),
                     }
        self.env['your.model'].create(product_data)
   else:
      # some code

return super(YourClass, self).create(vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add domain in raw material action as below :

```
<record id="product_raw_materials" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Raw Materials</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">product.template</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="context">{"search_default_filter_to_raw":1}</field>
        <field name="domain">[('raw','=',True)]</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="product.product_template_kanban_view"/>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="product.product_template_search_view"/>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Click to define a new product.
          </p><p>
            You must define a product for everything you sell, whether it's
            a physical product, a consumable or a service you offer to
            customers.
          </p><p>
            The product form contains information to simplify the Raw Materials: price, notes in the quotation, accounting data,
            procurement methods, etc.
          </p>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: It's not working. If i save in products by clicking the raw materials checkbox it gets saved in products form also. But it should not ,rather it should be saved in Raw materials menu only  that is what i'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

```
      I have found the answer for my question 

     <record id="raw_materials" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">raw.form.inherit.button</field>
                <field name="model">product.template</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml" >

                    <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="after">

                            <div name="options" groups="base.group_user">
                                <div>
                                    <field name="raw"/>
                                    <label for="raw"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>    

                    </xpath>

                </field>
            </record>

            <record id="***raw_search_view***" model="ir.ui.view"> 
            <field name="name">***raw.product.search***</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            ***<field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_search_view"/>***
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                ***<xpath expr="//filter[@name='consumable']" position="after">
                    <seperator/>
                    <filter string="Raw Materials" name="filter_to_raw" domain="[('raw','=',True)]"/>
                </xpath>***
            </field>
            </record>

            <record id="product_raw_materials" model="ir.actions.act_window">
                <field name="name">Raw Materials</field>
                <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
                <field name="res_model">product.template</field>
                <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
                <field name="view_type">form</field>
                ***<field name="context">{"search_default_filter_to_raw":True,"default_sale_ok":False}</field>***
                <field name="domain">[('raw','=',True)]</field>
                <field name="view_id" ref="product.product_template_kanban_view"/>
                <field name="search_view_id" ref="product.product_template_search_view"/>
                <field name="help" type="html">
                  <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                    Click to define a new product.
                  </p><p>
                    You must define a product for everything you sell, whether it's
                    a physical product, a consumable or a service you offer to
                    customers.
                  </p><p>
                    The product form contains information to simplify the Raw Materials: price, notes in the quotation, accounting data,
                    procurement methods, etc.
                  </p>
                </field>
            </record>



           <menuitem id="menu_mrp_product_form" name="Raw Materials" action="***product_raw_materials***"
                     parent="mrp.menu_mrp_bom" sequence="8"/>
```